# Execute one of the dataset based on one of the parameter value while each database has its own stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Friends,

I have created two datasets using two different stored procedures for a SSRS report, one fetches "summary" records when the stored procedure executes and other dataset fetches "detail" records.

The report has 4 parameters `@beginDate, @endDate, @renewalDate, @level`. When the user populates all the parameter `@level`, they get to select "summary" or "detail" from a drop down.

In the report body I have created two different tables one for summary records and one for details records (cannot do drill through or sub reports) to hold the dataset values

Based on the parameter `@level = "summary"` or `"detail"`, how can I execute the correct stored procedure for the dataset ?

Comment: out of curiosity, why not have just one stored procedure and have two tablix in your report.. One tablix showing details, one tablix doing the aggregation and showing summary(groupings etc) and hide one of them based on the parameter? Just an idea.

Comment: I can try that too, appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer after searching more...I this could be done by clicking the

Select the table or matrix report item, right-click, and then select Tablix Properties.

In the Tablix Properties dialog box, click the "Visibility" pane.

Change the display options by first changing the When The Report Is Initially Run option to Show Or Hide Based On An Expression.

---

=IIF(Parameters!pLevel.Value = "Summary",false,true)

=IIF(Parameters!pLevel.Value = "Detail",false,true)

---

More answers are welcome. Thanks!!

Comment: This does not achieve what your original question asked for.. run only one stored procedure.. rather it runs both but hides one from you..